# Self contained jar with Camel and Web Interface?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, apache-camel

I have had lots of trobule trying to get my head around how to solve this scenario:

We have an integration application that uses Camel for integration. This application also has a REST Api that exposes some services providing information about the application, for instance listing the active routes etc.

I have created a user interface for this using AngularJS that connects to these rest services. My main problem is how can I package this application as a self contained jar-file that provides the user interface and all the camel integration.

My working theory: Use a separate Jetty server to serve the Angular JS files and let Camel expose the REST services. The problem with this is CORS since the REST services reside on another port than the jetty server serving the Web UI.

Some requirements for the solution:

- Must be a single self contained jar-file.
- The camel integration is the main purpose, the Web UI is secondary
  and only used for trouble shooting. No need for a high performance
  web container since the Web ui is used by only a handful of users.

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now and it feels like I am over complicating the solution. Help on how to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at hawtio

- http://hawt.io/

as that is how we do that, hawtio is a web console for java, and has plugins for Camel. Its built using angularjs, and uses REST to communicate with the local or remote Java JVMs. To make the REST calls easier we use Jolokia.

Jolokia requires an agent to be embedded in the JVM, eg where Camel runs. Then that helps with CORS et all. http://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html#d0e2490

Comment: Thank you for the advice Claus, I will look at that more. Been using Hawtio before to inspect ActiveMQ, it´s a very handy tool!